# Compare string in 2 differents files python

Tags: python, string, file, compare, difflib

I need your help because after some long research I didn't find the appropriate answer to my problems.

I have 2 files which contain some information. Some of this information are similar others are different.
The first file is sorted the second one is not.

I tried to use the difflib but it doesn't work in my case , apparently.

Example

File 1 :

```
customerID: aa
companyName: AA
contacts: AAAA AAAA <aa@aa.fr>
```

File 2 :

```
customerID: zz
username: z.z
contacts: ZZZ ZZZ <zz@zz.com>
```

I need to find if the customerID is the same

Here is my code :

```
import sys
import string
import difflib                                               

def changes(file1, file2):
    # opening the 2 files which we need to compare                                 
    master = open(file1, 'r')
    slave = open(file2, 'r')

    # searching diff                                                               
    diff = difflib.unified_diff(master.readlines(),slave.readlines())
    t = ''.join(diff)
    print (t)




def main(argv=2):
    print (sys.argv[1])
    print (sys.argv[2])
    if argv == 2:
        changes(sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
    else:
        print ("This program need 2 files")
        exit (0)
    return 0

    if __name__ == '__main__':
   status = main()
   sys.exit(status)
```

Edit : The file are txt that i have formated like this myself.

Comment: Have you tried using regex to extract customerID info from both files and compare them?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to do. Do you want to check if all custermIDs from first file are also present in the second file?

Comment: I want to check if the customerID in the two files are the same and only print the ones which are not

Comment: maccinza No, i read a lot about python and mostly of my research are not ok with using regex and i don't know how to use regex

Comment: I suggest you to read https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html and build a regular expression to filter out the info you want from each file.

Comment: @maccinza I wiil read it thank you. I read a lot of documentation on the web

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with open('first.txt', 'r') as first_file:
   for line in first_file:
       data = line.split(":")
       if data[0].trim() == "customerID":
          customer_id  = data[1].trim()
          with open('second.txt', 'r') as second_file:
            for second_file_line in second_file:
            data2 = line.split(":")
            if data2[0].trim() == "customerID":
              if customer_id == data2[1].trim():
                <do your work>
```

If your files is too big then searching in second file is

```
with open('second.txt', 'r') as second_file:
for line in second_file:
    if customer_id in line:
       <do your work>
```

or if files are small enough then

```
if customer_id in open('second.txt').read():
      <do your work>
```

Comment: Yes i tried this didn't work properly as i wanted too.

Comment: Can you tell me about your problem which you faced when you tried it.

Comment: I didn't faced any technical problem only that when i used this method it printed like that :
customerID: ZZZ

customerID: WWWW

customerID: XXXX And i need to only have the value of the customerID to compare between the two files

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you need only customer ID like zzz,wwww,xxxx

so for this you can either split that line string or use regx.

Comment: That's it ! i need to only compare the value of the customerID in the two files.

Comment: Ok, you just need to compare only customerId not whole string. whole string may be diff but customer id will be same.

Comment: for above solution my assumption is your files are large.